# Sequence: $u_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Study the following sequence of numbers:
>   $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, u_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}}$$

I tried to calculate $u_{n+1}-u_n$, but I couldn't simplify the expression.

Plotting the sequence shows arithmetic (or seems to be an) progression.

Comment: what is the question that you are asking? Studying the sequence can mean a lot of things.

Comment: It usually means to calculate the limit and if possible, simplify the expression.

Comment: Clarity of question (as opposed to vagueness) is usually an important factor in getting help. So do you want to compute the limit or simplify the expression or both?

Comment: Hint: Divide top and bottom by k. Can you convert this to a riemann sum, hence an integral?

Comment: Using Riemann Sums, one can show that $\frac{u_n}n\sim\sqrt5-\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}} \ge n\cdot \frac{n}{\sqrt{2n^2}}=\frac{n}{\sqrt 2}$$

form which we conclude that $u_n \to \infty$, we can also obtain that

$$\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\le \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}} \le \frac{2n}{\sqrt{5}}$$

and by Riemann sum since

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac1n \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}}= \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac1n\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{\frac kn}{\sqrt{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}}=\int_1^2 \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 2$$

we obtain

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}}\sim (\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 2)n$$

Comment: okay that gives you a lower bound (which is tight for small $n$). Is there anything else that could be said given this bound ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi We can easily find the limit.

Comment: limit of $u_n$ ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Yes of course. It is a divergent sequence. Some other thoughts?

Comment: yes evidently it is divergent. I just thought you might also want to talk a bit about the rate of $u_n$ for large $n$.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi We can bound $$\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\le \sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}} \le \frac{2n}{\sqrt{5}}$$and by rieman sum obtain $\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}}\sim (\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 2)n $

Comment: yes that is amazing, I would love to see this in your answer so I can give you that $+1$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I'm waiting for the +1 now ;)

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, u_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}}\\ u_{n+1}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+2}\frac{k}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+k^2}}\\u_{n+1}-u_{n}=\underbrace{\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+2}\frac{k}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+k^2}}}_{n+2 \space terms}-\underbrace{\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+k^2}}}_{n+1 \space  terms}\\$$

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) we can get more detailed asymptotics, e.g.:

$$ u_n =  \left( \sqrt {5}-\sqrt {2} \right) n
+ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}
+\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{300}- \frac{\sqrt{2}}{48}  \right) n^{-1} +
\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{10000} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{1280} \right) n^{-3}
+O \left( {n}^{
-5} \right) $$

Comment: it's amazing... every time I see one of your anwers I learn something new